# sshpass Failed to Get a Pseudo Terminal in Windows 10 ubuntu linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Has anyone tried using sshpass in a windows 10 insider preview linux terminal?

It just returns this error

```
 root@T430U:~# sshpass -p mypass ssh user@host

 Failed to get a pseudo terminal: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314647/sshpass-throwing-error-failed-to-get-a-pseudo-terminal-success). You have to mount the `pts` directory:

```
m -rf /dev/ptmx
mknod /dev/ptmx c 5 2
chmod 666 /dev/ptmx 
umount /dev/pts
rm -rf /dev/pts
mkdir /dev/pts
vim /etc/fstab
    (added: none  /dev/pts  devpts  defaults 0 0)
mount /dev/pts
```

Comment: running last line - "mount /dev/pts" resulted in bluescreen in my case on win10 1703 :(